# Get value from directive into component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a directive that is used on input fields on my form. I am trying to get the value from that directive in my TS file

Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appOskInput]',
})
export class OskInputDirective implements OnInit {
  private isBlurTrue: boolean = false;

  @HostListener('focus')
  private onFocus() {
    console.log("focus");
    this.isBlurTrue = false;
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(true);
    this.subscribeToKeyboardEvents();
  }

  @HostListener("onBlur")
  private onBlur() {
    console.log("blur");
    this.isBlurTrue = true;
    this.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(false);
    this.unsubscribeFromKeyboardEvents();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<cb-form [formGroup]="setupForm">
  <form-input
    appOskInput
    (inputChanged)="onInputChanged($event,'accountNumber')"
    [formStatus]="formStatus"
    [parentFormGroup]="setupForm"
    [data]="{formControlName: 'accountNumber', name: 'accountNumber'}">
  </form-input>
</cb-form>
```

Essentially I want to use the `isBlurTrue` value in my TS file. Anyone knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

I just passed an output event in the directive

```
@Output() blurChanged = new EventEmitter();
```

Then emitted the value to it

```
this.blurChanged.emit(this.isBlurTrue);
```

In my HTML

I added

```
(blurChanged)="onBlurChanged($event)"
```

And in my TS I added

```
onBlurChanged(ev) {
  console.log(ev)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a `public` function within your directive where exposes your `private` property, and then use it in your template html from a parent control like this:

**Directive**

```js
...
private isBlurTrue: boolean = false;

getBlur(): boolean {
  return this.isBlurTrue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div #myDirective="appOskInput">
  ...
  <input (blur)="myDirective.getBlur()"/>
  ...
</div>
```